# Redirect to a page and pass the query parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One of my login pages has a href to register page, if user is not registered with the site.

```
<a href="register">Register if you haven't already</a>
```

But sometimes my login page has additional query parameters, which provides info on where user should be redirected to after successful login

```
 /login?next_page=next_page
```

When user clicks on Register link is there a way to pass all the query parameters to register page, so that after succesful registration user gets redirected to next_page

Comment: Can you define a click handler function for your registration anchor element?

Comment: I would probably store the parameters in a session variable

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); location.href = this.href + location.search; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the server-side to build this link dynamically using the querystring.
2. You can use the server-side in the "register" page to get the querystring from the referer header.
3. You can use javascript `location.search.slice(1)` to get the querystring and put it in the `<a>` tag.